# Spark driver taking whole resources on yarn cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn

we are submitting multiple sparks jobs in yarn-cluster mode to yarn queue simultaneously. The problem which we are facing currently is that drivers are getting initialized for all the jobs and  no resources are left for the executor's initializations.

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>          <value>0.5</value>
  <description>
      Maximum percent of resources in the cluster which can be used to run 
      application masters i.e. controls a number of concurrently running
      applications.
  </description>
</property>
```

According to this property, only 50% resources are available for application master but in our case, this is not working.
Any suggestions to tackle this problem.

Comment: The value for this property can be overridden with `yarn.scheduler.capacity.<queue-path>.maximum-am-resource-percent`. Do you see a value for that? And above that it even depends on the scheduler your cluster is configured to run on. Can you confirm these properties?

Comment: we have overrided this configuration for our queue. <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.scheduled.maximum-am-resource-percent</name><value>0.3</value> and we are using Capacity scheduler.